# How to discard selecting empty relationship items with another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'am querying the database like below as using laravel eloquent.

```
PostModel::with('images')->where('id', $id)->where('is_active', 1)->paginate(10);
```

In some cases there are no images for some posts, so there is an empty array for `images` property. What i need to know is how to discard the results having `empty array` for `images`. I don't want to run a `foreach` and remove the items and I'am looking for solution something in query side something like discarding the selection of those items. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about **has()**, **whereHas()** methods of Eloquent, url: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations  (heading: **Querying Relationship Existence**)

solution:

```
PostModel::with('images')->has('images')->where('id', $id)->where('is_active', 1)->paginate(10);
```

**or** You can use **join()** (which is more performant) : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins

Comment: owee oky thanks for the response :). but this is not selecting the `images`, this only select the **posts** which are having one or more images.

Comment: sorry forgot with('images')